# Error while running mapreduce program in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using **cdh4** and **eclipse juno**

While running the wordcount program I met with this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

I have already installed commons-lang3-3.1 jar file

Comment: check your classpath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing wrong class. From 3 on, the package is `org.apache.commons.lang3` not `org.apache.commons.lang`. You need to either use commons-lang-2*.jar or import proper class.